# How to configure route in MVC to pagination list

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, routes

I have this controller:

```
public class RestaurantController : Controller
{
public ActionResult Index(string name, int page = 0)
    {
        int pageSize = 4;

        @ViewBag.dropCitys = _db.Restaurantes.Select(c => c.Name).Distinct();

        var model = from res in
                        _db.Restaurantes
                        orderby res.Name descending
                    where ( (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)?  res.Name.Contains(name) : res.Name!="") )
                    select res;

        return View(model.Skip(pageSize * page).Take(pageSize).ToList());
    }
```

This is my Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
         "Restaurant",
         "{controller}/{action}/{page}",
         new { controller = "restaurant", action = "index", page= UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "MVCIntro.Controllers" } //usa-se isso para funcionar a AREA
         );}
```

I try to access the page like `mysite.com/restaurant/1 or mysite.com/restaurant/2` to reflect the pagination.

I receive `error 404`.

I think the route is incorrect, but I do not know how to configure it correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route is all wrong and should look like more like this :

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "Restaurant",
     "{name}/{page}",
     new { controller = "restaurant", action = "index", name= UrlParameter.Optional page= UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new string[] { "MVCIntro.Controllers" } //usa-se isso para funcionar a AREA
     );
```

but this will likely conflict with your default route so, this is more friendly

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "Restaurant",
     // find as it looks like you are searching for a reastraunt.
     "find/{name}/{page}",
     new { controller = "restaurant", action = "index", name= UrlParameter.Optional page= UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new string[] { "MVCIntro.Controllers" } //usa-se isso para funcionar a AREA
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute [HttpGet], and also try

mysite.com/restaurant?name=peter&page=1

or you can change the route to be

```
routes.MapRoute(
         "Restaurant",
         "{controller}/{action}/{page}",
         new { controller = "restaurant", action = "index", name="name", page= "page"},
            namespaces: new string[] { "MVCIntro.Controllers" } //usa-se isso para funcionar a AREA
         );}
```

and use the URL

```
mysite.com/restaurant/peter/1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your parameter as optional in the routeconfig.

```
page= UrlParameter.Optional
```

Your method indicates it is not optional. Changing your method so the page is optional might solve your issue. This will create a new issue as users can simply not enter a page number. You sovle this by checking if the page is null, if so: return page 0 (or 1, whatever you want). The new method will start with:

```
public ActionResult Index(string name, int? page = 0)
```